# Jquery, Childs get active one by one while parent li is active

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make the child elements of an `li` active when the parent `li` is active. So far I can switch from `li` to `li` and activate the children, but they don't show in order and they have random movement. If can anyone help me I would be very grateful.

```
var toggleChild = function() {
    $(".on span").children('a').children('span').removeClass('ready');
    $(".on span.active").removeClass().next().add(".on span:first").last().addClass("active").children('a').children('span').addClass('ready');
};

var toggleSlide = function() {
    $("#slider li.on").removeClass().next().add("#slider li:first").last().addClass("on");
    setInterval(toggleChild, 500);
};

setInterval(toggleSlide, 3000);
$("#slider .active a#open span").addClass("ready");​
```

Here is the link of what I have made so far. http://jsfiddle.net/MS5DV/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a recurring interval set to 3000 for `toggleSlide()`.

Though every call to toggleSlide start a new recurring interval to `toggleChild()`.

Every 3 seconds another half-second interval is started (and keeps on doing it forever).

Stopping an interval is done by:

```
var myIntervalId = setInterval(toggleSlide, 3000);
clearInterval(myIntervalId);
```

Though I think you mean to do a `setTimeout(toggleChild, 500);` inside `toggleSlide()`

Comment: Not working when i do that :/ 
The main objective is when the `li` is active, the spans inside will be  crossed, and the same to the next `li`.